# jquery sort element with array value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to sort some elements depend on it attribute. For an example:

```
<div id="sort">
<div n="1"></div>
<div n="2"></div>
<div n="3"></div>
<div n="4"></div>
</div>
```

And array_num

```
{3, 2, 1, 4}
```

pseudo code:

```
$('#sort').sort(array_num, 'n');
```

results will be:

```
<div id="sort">
<div n="3"></div>
<div n="2"></div>
<div n="1"></div>
<div n="4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there some kind of `logic` behind that order or do you need it just exactly like that?

Comment: `n` is not a valid `html tag` attribute. It will cause you some undesired behavior on some browser.

Comment: @jAndy: I want exactly like that :D
@Reigel: jquery have expando attribute itself.

Comment: yes, but that above is html and not jQuery :)

Comment: If you use jquery in IE, try to see innerHTML you will see expando attribute of Jquery in html tag ex: <div JQuery3312312313="12"></div>.

Comment: You might want to use `data-n` instead of `n`, see http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: @StoneHeart - yes in jQuery. but try it here, http://validator.w3.org/ , Oh well, all I can say is that it's not a good practice... ^^,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
​var order = [3, 2, 4, 1]​;
var el = $('#sort');
var map = {};

$('#sort div').each(function() { 
    var el = $(this);
    map[el.attr('n')] = el;
});

for (var i = 0, l = order.length; i < l; i ++) {
    if (map[order[i]]) {
        el.append(map[order[i]]);
    }
}
```

[Full code here](http://jsfiddle.net/FfFT9/)
​

Comment: Works excellently, even if an element in the $.each() is missing its attribute - just puts the element at the top. And it works when numbers in the `var order` are missing from the set of matched elements too.

Answer (score 5):

untested...

```
$.fn.asort = function (order, attrName) {
    for(var i = 0, len = order.length; i < len; ++i) {
        this.children('[' + attrName + '=' + order[i] + ']').appendTo(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this trying to fix what I was after. 
I took @shrikant-sharat's method and added a little to it as the attribute I needed to sort on was actually on a child element. Thought I'd add here in case it helps anyone (and for future me!)

```
$.fn.asort = function (order, attrName, filter) {
  console.log(this.length, order.length, order);
  for(var i = 0, len = order.length; i < len; ++i) {

    if(typeof(filter) === 'function') {
      filter(this.children(), attrName, order[i]).appendTo(this);
    } else {
      this.children('[' + attrName + '=' + order[i] + ']').appendTo(this);
    }
  }
  return this.children();
}
```

It allows you to pass a filter function to match the element you're after. It's not the most efficient I suppose, but it works for me, e.g.:

```
$('.my-list').asort(mapViewOrder, 'data-nid', function(items, attrName, val) {
  return items.filter(function(index, i) {
    return ($(i).find('[' + attrName + '="' + val + '"]').length);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery returns an array of objects, you may use the `sort` method, and then 'reappend' the children to the parent in the newly sorted order:

```js
var order = [3, 2, 1, 4];

var div = $('#sort');

div.children().sort((a, b) => {
  var aIndex = order.indexOf(parseInt(a.getAttribute('n')));
  var bIndex = order.indexOf(parseInt(b.getAttribute('n')));

  return aIndex - bIndex;
}).appendTo(div);
```

```css
#sort > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sort">
  <div n="1">1</div>
  <div n="2">2</div>
  <div n="3">3</div>
  <div n="4">4</div>
</div>
```