# What does this code do? (jQuery sort element with array value)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking for an answer to one of my questions and found this question right here:
 [jquery sort element with array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563370/jquery-sort-element-with-array-value)

And there is a brilliant answer from [fantactuka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242325/fantactuka) solving my problem. But I don't quite understand how this code works: [Full Code](http://jsfiddle.net/FfFT9/)

```
​var order = [3, 2, 4, 1]​;
var el = $('#sort');
var map = {};

$('#sort div').each(function() { 
    var el = $(this);
    map[el.attr('n')] = el;
});

for (var i = 0, l = order.length; i < l; i ++) {
    if (map[order[i]]) {
        el.append(map[order[i]]);
    }
}
```

Could someone explain what this part of his code does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript Loops**

Loops are handy, if you want to run the same code over and over again, each time with a different value.

Often this is the case when working with arrays:
Instead of writing:

```
text += cars[0] + "<br>";
text += cars[1] + "<br>";
text += cars[2] + "<br>";
text += cars[3] + "<br>";
text += cars[4] + "<br>";
text += cars[5] + "<br>";
```

You can write:

```
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    text += cars[i] + "<br>";
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

---

**ARRAY MAP**

Return an array with the square root of all the values in the original array:

```
var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];

function myFunction() {
    x = document.getElementById("demo")
    x.innerHTML = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
}
```

The result will be:
`2,3,4,5`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

---

**YOUR EXAMPLE**

```
​var order = [3, 2, 4, 1]​; //Map Order
var el = $('#sort'); //Get ID of target control
var map = {}; //Create empty map

$('#sort div').each(function() {  //For each control of ID ...
    var el = $(this); //Set el as input id ...
    map[el.attr('n')] = el; //add an attribute called n to each matching control
});

for (var i = 0, l = order.length; i < l; i ++) { //loop through array up to the length of array
    if (map[order[i]]) { //If map equals current iteration
        el.append(map[order[i]]); //Apply order
    }
}
```

---

**FLEXBOX**

On a side note the effect you are trying to achieve can be quite easy to achieve if you are willing to use the css3 `flex-box` which has sorting functionality.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp

Comment: thank you very much that helped me lot. The  `var map = {}` part confused me.

Comment: Will sure do. Another note i expected that when appending to the parent container it would "copy" the child and the result would look like this: 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 4. But i actually "cuts" out the div is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

So in first loop (each loop on div), he stores actual DOM elements in object named `map`. That means after completion of this loop we have a object like this:

```
map = {
    "1": div with attr 1,
    "2": div with attr 2,
    "3": div with attr 3,
    .
    .
}
```

Now we have one array in which we have store order of elements.

So in looping on that array [3, 2, 1, 4]:

```
when i = 0;
order[i] = 3
map[order[i]] = map[3] = div with attr 3 
appending this div on element

when i = 1;
order[i] = 2
map[order[i]] = map[2] = div with attr 2 
appending this div on element

when i = 2;
order[i] = 1
map[order[i]] = map[1] = div with attr 1 
appending this div on element
```

and so on

Comment: i expected that when appending to the parent container it would "copy" the child and the result would look like this: 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 4. But i actually "cuts" out the div is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code takes a list of DOM elements and reorders the elements in the specified fashion.

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxkrh0dr/1/)

```
var order = [3, 2, 4, 1]​;
var el = $('#sort');
var map = {};
```

In the above code, `order` holds the required arrangement, `el` references the container element.

```
$('#sort div').each(function() { 
    var el = $(this);
    map[el.attr('n')] = el;
});
```

Above, a `map` is created with current index vs DOM element. It looks like this:

```
map = {
    1: <element with n=1>, 
    2: <element with n=2>, 
    3: <element with n=3>, 
    4: <element with n=4>
}
```

Finally, the below code reorders the DOM by comparing `map` and `order`

```
for (var i = 0, l = order.length; i < l; i ++) {
    if (map[order[i]]) {
        el.append(map[order[i]]);
    }
}
```

The above loop runs this way:

```
el.append(map[3])
el.append(map[2])
el.append(map[4])
el.append(map[1])
```

Since you are appending an element already in `el` into `el`, `el.append` removes it and adds it to the end. That's how the reordering happens. [Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7058occL/) to understand that